# Keep having issues with Rstudio crashing/infinitely running

Tags: r, rstudio

this is my first time posting. So when I run this code into the Rstudio r command panel, the whole thing becomes very slow and this has only just started happening. Ive tried other applications and its only from Rstudio. I originally had a sample size of 10001 but reduced it to 50 and the same error occurs. Just wondering if this is a code problem or rstudio one.

Here is the following code:

```
 n <- 50
 smpl <- newdata[sample(nrow(newdata), 50),]
 plot(smpl$V37,smpl$V39,col="red", cex=.6)
```

The data itself is just coordinates in long lat, eg 150, -25. I have tested this data before without issue hence no data is supplied. I just wanted to know if anyone else has hit this issue before.

EDIT: sorry i forgot to mention my version is 2.15.3, 64bit windows vista enterprise, quad core 2.66GHz, 4gb of ram. I know this is not really code just wondering if anyone has hit the same issue with rstudio, it may be that my r version is corrupt or something.

Comment: You're trying to see if it's R or RStudio, so why not try that code in the base R gui?

Comment: I just have and it seems to be only this code now, I tried much more intensive plotting such as heatmapping with the same data and doesnt have any delay.

Comment: It seems to work with some random data I made                                 x<-c(128,129,130,131,132,140) 
 y<-c(-24,-25,-26,-28,-30,-33)
 plot(x,y,col="red", cex=.6)                                                  So it must be my data set then I guess, Just wondering how do you upload data for others to test as I have no clue how to, cheers for any help

Comment: I have had similar problems with RStudio on my windows box.  I can't reproduce the crash every time so haven't reported it.  I believe its an RStudio Windows thing.  Never occurs with Linux and RStudio.

Comment: Awesome, glad i'm not the only one who has run into it strange though how the code didn't work in the base R. Ill just try re-installing R, random packages recently have been corrupted the day after I've used them. I think it was also the amount of data and how I was plotting it that caused this.

Comment: I suspect for me it's the number of things using git operations but haven't really test too deeply.

Comment: I think it was the data I was using, the re-install didn't work so I think it is having problems with some missing fields.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve problems with an obsolete version?  You're going to go thru hell trying to install compatible package versions anyway.  D/L and install the latest RStudio and go on from there.